# Error - JSF project with Maven and IntelliJ

Tags: maven, jsf, intellij-idea

## What've done

I've created my **Maven** Project using **IntelliJ** IDE. After that, i had added the **JSF**'s module.

## What's Happening

I'm trying to execute my web aplication using the **Tomcat** web server.

The URL generated by the webserver is `http://localhost:8888/projeto-teste/web/olamundo.xhtml`, but the correct form would be `http://localhost:8888/projeto-teste/olamundo.jsf. Besides that, the page stays blank.

## My Project Environment

#### Folder Structure

[image]

#### Aplication Config

Confirming my libs folder, IntelliJ knows I have the mojarra instaled.

[image]

#### helloworld.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Teste Inicial JSF</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputText value="Olá Mundo" />
        <p>asdsadsa</p>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

#### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <!--   -->
    <display-name>projeto-teste</display-name>

    <!-- Indica que o JSF(FacesServlet) está instalado e responderá as requisições -->
    <servlet>
        <servelet-name>Faces Servlet</servelet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Mapeamento dos sufixos dos arquivos do front end -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Indica a fase de desenvolvimento do projeto. Com o "development", exceptions terão maior descrição -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Campos do formulário submitados em branco serão tratados como nulos -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

#### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>groupid-teste</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifacit-teste</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### I used this same Project on eclipse and it worked.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. You seem to be aware of the wrong and expected behavior. Aren't you basically asking how to make IntelliJ to open JSF pages on *.jsf URL pattern instead of *.xhtml URL pattern? If so, then why all that unnecessary code? This all is not caused by JSF code nor Maven configuration, but just by IDE itself.

Answer (score 0):

In web.xml, you mapped only *.jsf to the Faces Servlet.

So:

http://localhost:8888/projeto-teste/web/olamundo.xhtml - this URL will not be opened because *.xhtml is not mapped to Faces Servlet

http://localhost:8888/projeto-teste-livro/olamundo.jsf - this URL will not be opened because the context path is wrong (projeto-teste-livro instead of projeto-teste)

In other words, in your current configuration only this URL should work: 
http://localhost:8888/projeto-teste/olamundo.jsf

Just make sure IDEA will open this URL when starting Tomcat.

Comment: As I said, the project works on Eclipse. The URL mapping is correct. The *.jsf file only specify it will be executed like a .jsf

Comment: How are you building the war that you're deploying - with maven or with IDEA?